# Oracle 12c Opatch failed with error code 73

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, patching

I don't find a solution for the following Opatch Error:

D:\oracle\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\cfgtoollogs\opatch\opatch2017-07-05_22-29-53PM_1.log

```
05.07.2017 22:29:53]        OPatch invoked as follows: 'lsinventory -xml d:\oracle\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\QOpatch\xml_file.xml -retry 0 '
[05.07.2017 22:29:53]        Could not get central inventory using NGOUI; oracle.sysman.nextgen.utils.NextGenInventoryUtil
[05.07.2017 22:29:53]        OUI-67077:
                             Oracle Home       : d:\oracle\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1
                             Zentrales Bestandsverzeichnis: C:\Program Files\Oracle\Inventory
                                von           : n/a
                             OPatch-Version    : 12.1.0.1.10
                             OUI-Version       : 12.1.0.2.0
                             OUI-Speicherort      : d:\oracle\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\oui
                             Speicherort von Log-Datei : d:\oracle\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\cfgtoollogs\opatch\opatch2017-07-05_22-29-53PM_1.log
[05.07.2017 22:29:53]        Patch history file: d:\oracle\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\cfgtoollogs\opatch\opatch_history.txt
[05.07.2017 22:29:54]        Starting LsInventorySession at Wed Jul 05 22:29:54 CEST 2017
[05.07.2017 22:29:54]        [OPSR-MEMORY-1] : after installInventory.getAllCompsVect() call : 53 (MB)
[05.07.2017 22:29:54]        [OPSR-MEMORY-2] : before loading cooked one off : 61 (MB)
[05.07.2017 22:29:55]        [OPSR-MEMORY-3] : after loading rawOneOffList and before loading minipatch list in cooked one off : 76 (MB)
[05.07.2017 22:29:55]        [OPSR-MEMORY-4] : after filling cookedOneOffs and when inventory is loaded.. : 76 (MB)
[05.07.2017 22:29:55]        Lsinventory Output file location : d:\oracle\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\cfgtoollogs\opatch\lsinv\lsinventory2017-07-05_22-29-53PM.txt
[05.07.2017 22:29:55]        --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[05.07.2017 22:30:01]        Could not get central inventory using NGOUI; oracle.sysman.nextgen.utils.NextGenInventoryUtil
java.net.UnknownHostException: HOSTNAME: HOSTNAME
               at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1409)
               at oracle.sysman.oii.oiin.OiinNetOps.computeNICList(OiinNetOps.java:105)
               at oracle.sysman.oii.oiin.OiinNetOps.<init>(OiinNetOps.java:76)
               at oracle.sysman.oii.oiin.OiinNetOps.getNetOps(OiinNetOps.java:90)
               at oracle.sysman.oii.oiix.OiixNetOps.getFullHostName(OiixNetOps.java:49)
               at oracle.opatch.InventoryInstance.<init>(InventoryInstance.java:149)
               at oracle.opatch.LsInventoryToXML.createXML(LsInventoryToXML.java:228)
               at oracle.opatch.LsInventoryToXML.process(LsInventoryToXML.java:196)
               at oracle.opatch.LsInventorySession.loadAndPrintInventory(LsInventorySession.java:460)
               at oracle.opatch.LsInventorySession.process(LsInventorySession.java:317)
               at oracle.opatch.OPatchSession.main(OPatchSession.java:2119)
               at oracle.opatch.OPatch.main(OPatch.java:634)
```

C:\Program Files\Oracle\Inventory\logs\OPatch2017-07-05_10-11-59-PM.log
    INFO: Umgebungsvariablen:

```
INFO:   ORACLE_HOME = D:\oracle\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1

INFO:   PATH = d:\oracle\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\bin;d:\oracle\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\OPatch;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\IBM\ITM\bin;C:\IBM\ITM\TMAITM6;C:\IBM\ITM\InstallITM

INFO:   CLASSPATH = 

INFO: Benutzername:xxxxx

INFO: Creating a new Install area Control for this inventory session with new  access level  0

INFO: Install area Control created with access level  0

INFO: Creating a new Install area Control for this inventory session with new  access level  1

INFO: Install area Control created with access level  1

INFO: Ending the inventory Session 
INFO: Disposing the install area control objects
```

The last patch worked. The system was not changed since the last patch. What could be the reason?

Comment: Looks like a hostname resolution problem

Answer (score 1):

Even when I stopped all Oracle services there was a [user using sqlplus](https://support.symantec.com/en_US/article.TECH218616.html). This seems to have created the problem.